# Why is indexOf returning -1 if no match has been found?

Tags: javascript, indexof

> *str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])*
>
> The index of the first occurrence of searchValue, or **-1 if not found**.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)

Why was `-1` chosen to be the returned value by `.indexOf` if it doesn't find a match in the array?

```js
console.log([].indexOf()) // -> -1
```

Would it not be more suitable to have `0` instead? It would make sense because there are indeed `0` matching element. And this way we could have used it directly in a conditional statement, for example:

```
if( Array.indexOf(String) ) { ... }
```

Instead of

```
if( Array.indexOf(String) !== -1 ) { ... }
```

Why is that? Any particular reason? I've seen the same in Java, C++ and C. Is this because of how the native function was designed?

Comment: The function returns the first **index** (i.e. the position) where the value was found. Remember that in all languages you mentioned the first index of an array is `0`.

Comment: The first index in an array is 0: `[1,2,3].indexOf(1) :0`

Comment: It show's the position, it's not just a boolean of whether it exists or not

Comment: There is a class of questions that pretty much always gets down voted or blocked, which is architectureal design questions.  I actually like the architectural design questions.  There is a lot of insight to be gained in computer science by understaing those.  Ivan is asking a pretty basic question, but it gets to a discussion of origin 1 vs 0 array addressing, as well as folding error codes into results.  I think Stephen Rauch blocked this to limit the obvious answers.  FORTRAN, PASCAL, and Lua were 1 origin but newer languages like C, python, and Javascript tend to 0 origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone else is saying the same thing, but let me try another wording of the answer.

In Javascript arrays are indexed starting with element 0.  So if the string qas found at the begining the valid return value would be 0.  If string not found was reported as 0 you would not know if it was not found or found at the beginning.  -1 is never a valid value for a position in a string.

As to your test

`if( Array.indexOf(String) ) { ... }`

you could instead use

`if( 1+Array.indexOf(String) ) { ... }`

to avoid using the !== -1 test.

As a general consideration, the result of Array.indesOf() is overloaded. The result contains both the funciton result and an error code.  This overloading allows the function call to be used directly in a test.  Consider, however, that if the function call is in the if statement you probably will need to call the function again, which is an efficiency loss.  If before the if you made an assignment of the result and then tested the result you would be computationally more efficient.  There is not even a memory cost because variables in funtions are on the stack which is cleared on function return if you keep the variable local.

A function that returned a structure containing a success/fail flag and a result is a clean way to do such a thing that generalizes function calls that may fail, and is a convenient place to put exception handling without complicating the simple test you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it not be more suitable to have 0 instead?

No. Indexes start from zero.

```js
var str = "ABC";
console.log(str[0]);
console.log(str.indexOf("A"));
```

(The same is true of arrays, which you used for your examples despite quoting the documentation for strings).

Comment: Worth mentioning `includes`, as it would give OP's expected output?

Comment: Indexes start from zero in programming...with very few exceptions (such as Visual Basic's `Strings.InStr` method, since traditionally in BASIC indexes started with 1).

Comment: You are correct that it would be much better to use zero, but then they would have to re-write many languages so they were not zero based and all the code that has been written in the last 50 years might need to be re-written.  So it would be a big step to change it now.

Answer (score 3):

Well. It's pretty straight forward as to why. `indexOf` returns the position of an element not if it exists or not. Plus all ( 99% ) programming languages are `0` indexed, or better say `strings` and `arrays` are 0 indexed which means that the first element is at position 0.

Think of position as the `offset` of an element from the start of the array. So the distance/offset of the first element from the start of the array is, well, 0 :)

Maybe you are looking for `includes()` which checks if an element is inside an array.

```js
const arr=[1,2,3]
// classic
if (!arr.includes(4)) {
  console.log('4 does not exist (classic)')
}

// or short circuit

!arr.includes(4) && console.log('4 does not exist (short circuit)')

// conditional (ternary) operator

!arr.includes(4) ? console.log('4 does not exist (ternary)') : ""
```

**Observation**

Also you shouldn't use `indexOf()` as a boolean condition because for example

```js
let arr=['a','b','c']

arr.indexOf('a') ? console.log('true') : console.log('false')
```

In the above example, `indexOf(a)` returns it's position `0`. In a boolean condition `0` is treated as false by javaScript. So it would not give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Because in almost every programming language, 0 is the first position of an array.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` gives you the position of the element in the array and valid index of array starts from `0, 1, ...` and so on till the `array.length-1` so if the `indexOf()` would return `0` for non existence element then that would be incorrect as `0` is a valid index. Thus `-1` is used.